# how to add a function to a button thats within a button on Tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, command

Im trying to add a command on newButton where when clicked, it shows a new blank page where i can then enter several input boxes and labels  (almost like a survey)
I'm just not sure how to add a command to the 'START' button, to do all of this.

This is the section of the code:

```
# create label text
myLabel_1 = Label(window, bg="black", text=" enter Name ")
myLabel_1.grid(row=0, column=0)


# give button function
def myClick():

    myLabel = Label(text="Hello " + e.get() + "...     text ", bg='black')
    myLabel.grid(row=60, column=0)


# new button for new page
    newButton = Button(window, bg='white', text="START",
                       padx=50, pady=20, fg='green')
    newButton.grid()


# destroy previous widgets
    myButton.destroy()
    e.destroy()
    myLabel_1.destroy()


# create button 1
myButton = Button(window, bg='black', text="next", command=myClick)
myButton.grid(row=0, column=13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just re-`configure` the existing `myButton` once it's been clicked and calls `myClick()`, same with `myLabel`. There's no need to destroy these widgets only to recreate them later.

```
def start():
    pass


def myClick(lbl, btn):  # add parameters to accept the label and button objects
    # update the label
    lbl.configure(text="Hello " + e.get() + "...     text ", bg='black')
    # update the button
    btn.configure(bg='white', text="START", padx=50, pady=20, fg='green', command=start)


myLabel = Label(window, bg="black", text=" enter Name ")
myLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

myButton = Button(window, bg='black', text="next")
myButton.configure(  # configure the button's command after declaring it
    # using a lambda to pass the label and button objects to 'myClick'
    command=lambda lbl=myLabel, btn=myButton: myClick(lbl, btn)
)
myButton.grid(row=0, column=13)
```

Comment: hey, when i do that, it says that myClick and myLabel are not defined. therefore it wont run. sorry about this im very new @JRiggles

Comment: just myClick acctually

Comment: That's a scoping problem - I've edited my answer!

Comment: Should the two arguments of `myClick()` be used instead of `myLabel` and `myButton` inside the function?

Comment: Yep - missed that in the edit. Fixed now.